# What language is used to develop a Bloomberg App Portal application

Tags: bloomberg

What language would a developer use to develop an application for the Bloomberg App Portal as described here: [Bloomberg press room](http://www.bloomberg.com/pressroom/bloomberg-launches-enterprise-app-portal-to-financial-markets/)

To be specific, I'm not asking on how to integrate with BBG on the desktop via the Anywhere APIs. This is a question deploying a custom "app" within the terminal.

Perhaps a follow up question that should be asked separate is, has any small firm successfully deployed an app there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this link singledealerplatforms.org/tag/bloomberg-app-portal/ the language used is C#,

```
For $500 per month, developers will be given access to a Software Development Kit (SDK), documentation, data feed, up to 3 Terminals and developer support
Apps are subject to code review before being accepted onto the Portal
Apps are written in C# using .NET and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
```

According to this link www.moneymanagement.com.au/product-news/2012/bloomberg-app-portal-financial-services-software the App Portal is designed so that a PhD student could publish their own app - they may be speaking of a real case here.

If you do some more searching, you'll come across a couple of apps that look like they're from small/new companies, why not email them and ask?   http://www.percentageit.com/ for example is a small company that develops apps for third parties as well, http://www.bbapplabs.com is similar for Asia

Comment: Thanks. Can't wait to see more apps.

Answer (score 4):

I am actually developping an application for bloomberg App Portal.

You have to use C# and WPF for programming (like for windows8 app)

Today there is 70 apps available, most of them are from small/middle firm.

Bloomberg provides 3 developing teminal for 2500$/month (30000/year), it also authorize to have up to 25 users. Then you have to pay 1000$ by 100 additional users

This cost can be prohibitive. I think it is why there is only 70apps after 1.5 year.